# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary' while using tradingview_ta library

Tags: python, trading, tradingview-api, ta-lib

I am getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary' after some displaying some output of my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from tradingview_ta import TA_Handler, Interval, Exchange

stkfilename = f"F:/Python/HistoricStockInfo/StockName.csv"
stkFile = pd.read_csv(stkfilename)
for i in range(len(stkFile)):
    #print(stkFile['Symbol'].iloc[i])
    NIFTY = TA_Handler(
    symbol=stkFile['Symbol'].iloc[i],
    #symbol = "ACE",
    screener="india",
    exchange="NSE",
    interval=Interval.INTERVAL_1_WEEK
    )

    result = NIFTY.get_analysis().summary
    if NIFTY.get_analysis().summary: 
        summary = (result.find('summary').text or '').encode('utf8')

    #if result['RECOMMENDATION']=="STRONG_BUY":
    if result is None:
        print(stkFile['Symbol'].iloc[i])
        print(result)
    else:
        print("Symbol not found")
```

Here is my code.

What I am trying to do it to read Stock Symbols from my excel file and pass it to TA_*handler function to get result using get_analysis method. Trying to print the results of symbols found on trading view as per criteria.*

Giving me below error after some output.

```
5PAISA
{'RECOMMENDATION': 'SELL', 'BUY': 6, 'SELL': 10, 'NEUTRAL': 10}
63MOONS
{'RECOMMENDATION': 'SELL', 'BUY': 3, 'SELL': 14, 'NEUTRAL': 9}
A2ZINFRA
  File "f:\Python\datacheck.py", line 27, in <module>
    result = NIFTY.get_analysis().summary
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

> What I am trying to do it to read Stock Symbols from my excel file and pass it to TA_*handler function to get result using get_analysis method. Trying to print the results of symbols found on trading view as per criteria.*

SymbolName.csv looks like below..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irnKa.png)

Comment: Please provide an example `StockName.csv` file to make your problem completely repeatable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the whole code which works for me... Adding StockName.csv though...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: No actually... I am getting error after printing some output from the code.. That means my code is accepting input processing it and providing output till some extent. (A2ZINFRA) Till I found this stock. 

Next stock name is AAATECH which I am able to find on trading view but it is giving error while running this code....